# Django Rest Framework Getting serializer from model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am looking for a way to get a serializer from a model class. This is so that I can easily serialize model data, without having to harcode the serializer name and I figured something like this would do:

```
#mymodels.py
from django.db import models
import myserializers

class Model(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  serializer = serializers.Serializer
```

```
#myserializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
import mymodels

class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = mymodels.Model
    fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

The model is for an intermediary relationship, and I want a function that will act something like this:

```
def serialize(to_serialize):
  return type(to_serialize).serializer(to_serialize).data
```

But this raises a `AttributeError`due to import errors. Am I going about this the completely wrong way? Is there an easier way of doing this, or is there a way to make this work somewhat like the above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to put the serializer in the model? Why not just use ModelSerializers  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Comment: @RedCricket I have multiple intermediary relationship models and a function that can handle multiple types of relationships, so I figured the easiest way to get the serializer without having to type out the actual name of it in the function would be to assign the serializer to the model. I'll update the post to clarify it a bit.

Comment: is serilalizer different for every object? or same for every object in model Model?

Comment: @paras chauhan yes, there will be multiple models with different fields, so if im correct I need a different serializer for each.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way may be work for you:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    serializer = serializers.Serializer
    class Meta:
        serializer_class = SerailizerClassName
```

In this code serializer set in model 
now use the serializer in method

```
def serialize(model_object):
  return model_object.__class__.Meta.serializer_class(model_object).data
```

Comment: Unable to test this now, but I would imagine that moving it to an inner class would indeed work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that this would not work if you are using Model Serializer